# How to read Windows default Gateway IP address in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Can some body point me how to read the default windows gateway IP address in C++. I am able to read the list of all the IP addresses using GetAdaptersInfo() but not the default gateway IP address.

```
   GetAdaptersInfo( pAdapterInfo, &BufferLength );
 // Iterate the network adapters and print their MAC address.
    while( pAdapterInfo )
    {           
        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next; // Get next adapter info
    }
```

Here is the code snippet and wondering which field gives me the default gateway. I can get the gateway of every IP address in the list but I need the default gateway IP address.

The original reason for wanting this was to select the specific MAC address (from the bunch of MAC addresses) of the IP which has got the default gateway.  As we get multiple MAC addresses while iterating thru the list, we thought the best way is pick up the MAC address of the IP which has the default gateway.  We have since changed our minds, and will choose the wired connection MAC address.  But I am still curious to know how to get the default gateway instead of iterating thru all the adapters.

Answer (score 3):

[`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you this:

> GatewayList
>
> Type: IP_ADDR_STRING
>
> The IPv4 address of the gateway for this adapter represented as a linked list of IP_ADDR_STRING structures. An adapter can have multiple
>   IPv4 gateway addresses assigned to it. This list usually contains a
>   single entry for IPv4 address of **the default gateway for this adapter**.

Maybe you need to post your code if you are unable to get the gateway from `GetAdaptersInfo` data you are already having.

Basically you can "preview" this information by running `ipconfig /all` from commend prompt. You will see gateways are defined per interface, there is no global gateway. `route print` gets you routes and you can see they are prioritized and this stipulates whether this or that gateway is effectively used: it depends on which route is taken.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.May be I misunderstood the way it works. I was thinking there will be an API which gives me default gateway instead of traversing through the entire list. My plan is to find the default GW and traverse through the entire list to see which IP address uses the default GW.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use WINAPI, [GetAdapterAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may just be the best option.

```
GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_GATEWAYS | GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_ALL_INTERFACES | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST
```

The documentation for the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES function is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, you would use GetAdaptersInfo (as per Roman R's answer) or preferably GetAdapterAddresses (as per specializt's answer) to list the adapters, and exactly one adapter would have exactly one gateway configured.  However, it is possible to have more than one default gateway, though it is [not recommended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157025).  However, on a computer that has multiple default gateways, I believe that the [GetBestRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function will tell you which one is currently in use.  Note that this may change at any time.

Only if multiple adapters have gateways configured would you need to call GetBestRoute to decide which of the default gateways is most likely to be used for any given connection.   Keep in mind that if there is more than one default gateway, none of them is considered inherently "better" than the others; in other words, in this scenario there's no such thing as "the default gateway" there's only "the default gateways".

Comment: Will this call guarantees to give default gateway IP? Is "route print" uses the same call internally?

Comment: On the only multihomed machine I have available to play with, "route print" does not show which default gateway is currently in use, it just lists the default gateways for each adapter, i.e., exactly what `GetAdaptersInfo` gives you.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Original Idea was to pick up the MAC address (from the bunch of MAC addresses) of the IP which has got default gateway. As we get multiple MAC addresses while iterating thru the list, we thought the best way is pick up the MAC address of the IP which has default gateway. But now we changed our mind, to pick up the wired connection MAC address. But still i was curious to know how to get the default gateway instead of iterating thru all the adapters.

Comment: please stop making assumptions - there are WINAPI-functions for getting the chosen / to be choosen gateway.

Comment: @specializt: such as?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.gatewayaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx
Google is your friend.

Comment: @specializt: that just returns the gateway addresses for a particular adapter.  In fact, it's just the .NET version of the function the OP was already using, GetAdaptersInfo, so it's completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: neither have you even looked at the link nor do you know what you're talking about. There is no ".NET version" of _ANY_ WINAPI-function, all of the .NET-code is completely autonomous and doesnt even call WINAPI (.NET-methods may be implemented in a similar way, though). The above Property (!) is EXACTLY what he was asking about - i could continue and provide a CLR-example of this, even the native method is well within my capabilities but im afraid you wont even be able to compile anything ... sorry. Next time : dont ask questions you dont answers for, please.

Comment: @specializt: I read the link; it says that IPInterfaceProperties.GatewayAddresses returns the gateway addresses for a given adapter.  Roman R.'s answer already showed the OP how to do this.  You claimed that there was a function which would retrieve *the* "chosen / to be choosen gateway" even if there is more than one default gateway configured, but the documentation you linked to says nothing of the sort.

Comment: @specializt: you do understand that I'm talking about the OPs second question (how to select one particular default gateway when there is more than one) rather than the original question?

Answer (score 0):

It simply doesn't work this way - the settings window is showing default gateway for given interface, but there is no such thing as default gateway for entire system. Again settings window will try to be helpful and suggest seting one or another network interface as default, but what really happens if you do so is ading a default entry in a [routing table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table). The thing is that more advanced setups will enable you for example use different interfaces (or even gateways) depending on destination address. If you want your default gateway for purpose of comunicating some specific address, you can use [GetBestRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - it will tell you which gateway you would have used if you wanted to contact given address. If you want to get just a generic default gateway for your computer you might try to scan through routing table, but it's a nasty thing to do, and there might not even be something to be identified as single default-gateway there, there might be multitude of them - the system will usually "just work" anyway, but it might get tricky to get your program find that out.

To sumarize: there is no such thing a computer-wide default gateway. Desktop Windows are usually set-up in a way which resembles that, but that is not a strict requirement. Even if it is so, it is done using lower level mechanism (routing table), and reading it's configuration can get nasty - I know, I've done it ;)

Another idea - the control panel probably keeps those settings somewhere in the registry, for the system to be able to configure networking on every system start. If you find uot where those are, you might not get the 100% netorking-oriented default gateway, but you will surely get the value user sees in settings window. I don't know where to look for such knowledge and I suspect that it's not published, and kept as implementation detail - mening that it can change from version to version, and  even with some bigger updates/Service Packs. If you go this way, it will most likely not be portable between different windows versions.

PS Why do you need this? Why would anyone need this?

Comment: Educated guess: he wants a MAC address for licensing reasons, to tie an activation code to a particular machine.  Since there is usually more than one MAC address he needs a consistent way to choose a particular one.  If there were indeed such a thing as *the* default gateway, the MAC address of the associated adapter would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: @HarryJohnston reasonable choice? And what if the user uses laptop and sometimes connects it via cable - to get better speed, but sometimes wanders around his flat with laptop on wifi... What happens to his default gateway MAC address? Since you can change you MAC, provided your computers are on different subnets you can effectively fool your lincesed software. I would rather go for motherboard serial number in such case. At least there is no ready-to-apply method around it.

Comment: Good point; the "preferred default gateway" (even if it existed) would not be a sensible criteria, at least for software liable to be run on a laptop.  MAC address is the conventional choice, though, partly I think because not all motherboards expose the serial number to software.  Speaking as a system administrator, I'd say that the fact that it can be overridden if necessary is a feature, not a bug: customers are liable to get cross if they suffer extra downtime because an emergency hardware replacement caused licensing to fail (and couldn't be overridden).

Comment: @HarryJohnston So if I understand you right, first software vendors implement licensing system to lock software to a single machine using it's MAC address, then hardware vendors make it changeable to allow hardware replacement. I fail to see the point of this situation. If it is so important to keep your server running and possibly change hardware, then what is licensing system for? PS I know main reason to change MAC are possible collisions within switched networks.

Comment: It isn't (or shouldn't be) necessary to be able to change MAC addresses in order to avoid collisions; the default address burnt into the hardware should always be unique.  I believe the feature was designed to allow MAC addresses to be based on layer 3 addresses; IP doesn't use this, but DECNet used to IIRC.

Comment: A MAC-based licensing system still provides protection against accidental or casual licensing violations, and in the event of a lawsuit could serve as evidence that any particular violation was indeed intentional.  So it isn't pointless, IMO.